# How to print particular student details by searching only firstName in postman using specification class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, specifications

Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [experience] on this ManagedType [com.studentManagement.model.Student]......this is error shown in console.

This is the code I did it in Specifcation class..

```
@Component
public class StudentSpecification {
    public Specification<Student> getStudents(Student request){

        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) ->{

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (request.getEmail() != null && !request.getEmail().isEmpty()) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("email"), request.getEmail()));
        }
        if (request.getFirstName() != null && !request.getFirstName().isEmpty()) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get("firstName")),
                    "%" + request.getFirstName().toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }
}

**Service Class**
```

public List getStudentList(Student request) {

```
        List<Student> students=studentRepository.findAll(studentSpecification.getStudents(request));
        return students;    
    }
```

I am expecting to print student details for particular student I searched

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems obvious enough.

> Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [experience] on this ManagedType [com.studentManagement.model.Student].

Your `Student` object class doesn't have an attribute named with `experience`.

Please check inside your student class and make sure you configure it correctly.